# Intellij Idea - how to run plugin

Tags: plugins, ide, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm as a Python IDE. I've downloaded Quick Notes plugin which should give me an ability to write notes to make my code more clear ([Link to Quick Notes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=4456)).

[image: Quick Notes is installed]

The problem is that I couldn't find a way how to use it. There is no option to "run" this plugin. I checked many web pages about Intellij Idea plugins but with no success.

Could you give me an advice how to use plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I spend some time to find control to run it.

"Notes" on right vertical bar or Ctrl+Shift+A and enter "Notes"

P.S. Different plugins used different ways to run.
V.